# Do anyone has the source caman js example on site?

Tags: camanjs

I am trying to create the functionality like this page url : http://camanjs.com/examples/ for image filters.

I have tried with this code.

```
 var img_map = Caman("#test-canvas", "../images/test1_640.jpg");

//update brightness
   function update_brightness(value){
        //img_map.revert();
        img_map.brightness(value).render();
   }

//update contrast
    function update_contrast(value){
        //img_map.revert();
        img_map.contrast(value).render();
   }
```

The changes on image are not like the site i am refering.
The  main issue is when i increase any control then it works fine. But when I try to decrease the control value then it does not work.

To control the value for brightness or contrast i have used "range" input.

```
        <img id="test-image" src="../images/test1_640.jpg" />
        <canvas id="test-canvas"></canvas>
brightness
<input onchange="update_brightness(this.value);" type ="range" min ="-100" max="100" step ="10" value ="0"/>

contrast
<input onchange="update_contrast(this.value);" type="range" min="-100" max="100" step="" value="0">
```

Comment: no am asking for the help. As i had not get the source may anyone know it or have another code sample for the example

Comment: ok let me change the description.

Comment: Hope you understand my problem and provide appropriate input.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT:  I just compiled the coffeescript out to JavaScript and put it in a repo of my own for (hopefully) easier use:

https://github.com/nbieber/CamanJS-example

---

You can find the original source here: https://github.com/meltingice/CamanJS-Site/blob/master/_assets/javascripts/examples.js.coffee

It's in coffeescript, though.

Comment: Thanks! That's all I wanted ( just please /images by images and it works perfectly)

Answer (score 0):

You can add

`this.revert(true);`

in your update_brightness and update_contrast functions.

```
function update_brightness(value){
    //img_map.revert();
    this.revert(true);
    img_map.brightness(value).render();
```

}